# React function for making multiple class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So, I have a class component that loads some data from API:

```
class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: {}
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(item_url[0])
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state.output);
    const { general = {name:"", description:""} } = this.state.output;
    const { brand = {name : ""} } = this.state.output;
    const { id } = this.state.output;
    const {images = {primary:{large:""}}} = this.state.output;
  return (
    <ItemPanel>
    <ItemBox>
    <BoxTitle>{general.name}</BoxTitle>
    <BoxId>Item ID: {id}</BoxId>
    <Details onClick={show_details}>Show more...</Details>
        <Inline>
        <Quantity type="number" defaultValue="1"></Quantity>
        <Icon>add_shopping_cart</Icon>
        </Inline>
        <AddItem>
        <Sfont>Add to cart</Sfont>
    </AddItem>
    </ItemBox>
        <BoxImg src={images.primary.large} alt='img error'></BoxImg>
   </ItemPanel>
  );
}
}
export default Item;
```

It works correctly with the API, address (URL) is inserted from this array:

```
let item_url = [
'http://localhost:3005/products/774944', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/774945', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/774946',
'http://localhost:3005/products/123581', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782691', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782485',
'http://localhost:3005/products/782486', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782487', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782488',
'http://localhost:3005/products/738471'];
```

What I want to achieve here is a function that renders this component multiple times (every time with another API data). I guess some kind of loop function is needed here, but can't figure it out. It is now rendered from my index.js like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Item from './DataHarvester'

ReactDOM.render([<Item />, <App />], document.getElementById('root'));
```

But obviously, it creates only one component while I need to have 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to do this; typically the pattern is as follows:

1. Parent components requests data and places the result into some form
   of state
2. Within the render of the parent component, `map` over that
   state to produce child  components
3. Child components can then render
   the data which they are passed from the parents

```js
const Section = (props) => (
  <p>{props.url}</p>
);

const App = () => {
  const urls = [
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774944',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774945',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774946',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/123581',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782691',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782485',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782486',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782487',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782488',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/738471'
  ];
  
  return (
    <div>
      {urls.map(x => <Section url={x}/>)}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('r'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="r"></div>
```